# Auto logon fails on Windows 10 1709 devices

Tags: domain, windows-10, automation

Recently we re-imaged a computer lab to bring it up to spec with the latest updates, and some of the computers in this lab (HP EliteOne 800 G2 all-in-ones) are run without keyboard or mouse, and are wall mounted. Traditionally, we have had them auto logon so that they can be run without a touchscreen.

They are running Windows 1709 build 16299.371

After the image, everything worked great. They would auto logon immediately (there is a pre-configured domain account they point to). However after one weekend, all of the computers will not logon any more. It works fine if you login manually, but that is extremely inconvenient.

I have heard that auto-logon can be temperamental at times, but I find it strange that all four computers stopped at the same time.

If you have any idea what might be happening at all, please help!

Other random info:
Doesn't log onto any domain account automatically.
We were told that they were seen updating, however there is no record of installed updates since the image.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The last time I had a system like this...
If anyone did a manual console logon with a different username, that would overwrite at least one of the registry keys and it would stop doing auto logons. Check security log for logons with other account names, or just fix the keys.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
DefaultUserName = bart
DefaultPassword = te!!N0one
AutoAdminLogon = 1
```

Comment: So oddly enough all of those keys are correct. Still no luck, but thank you!